# Bean validation constraint Pattern: match N digits regexp not working in XML

Tags: regex, bean-validation, valdr-bean-validation

Bean validation constraint Pattern(match N digits regexp) not working if specified in XML. e.g.,

```
public class Foo {
    @Pattern(regexp="\\d{10}")
    private String phoneNumber;
}

phoneNumber: 1234567890
```

Annotation works.

XML:

```
<bean class="Foo">
        <field name="phoneNumber">
            <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Pattern">
                <element name="regexp">\\d{10}</element>
            </constraint>
        </field>
</bean>
```

Error:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: phoneNumber: must match the following regular expression: \d{10}
```

If changing pattern to:

```
 <element name="regexp">\d{10}</element>
```

Error:

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2793)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2747)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
    at org.apache.bval.util.Exceptions.lambda$create$1(Exceptions.java:49)
    at org.apache.bval.util.Exceptions.create(Exceptions.java:58)
    at org.apache.bval.util.Exceptions.create(Exceptions.java:49)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.metadata.XmlBuilder.loadClass(XmlBuilder.java:531)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:545)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
```

What is the equivalent XML for `@Pattern(regexp="\\d{10}")`?

Comment: Have you tried double-double escape `\\\\d{10}` or `[0-9]{10}`?

Comment: \\\\d{10} not working.  [0-9]{10} works. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helps, I've made this comment an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is the regex flavour, but, if `\d` doesn't work, I think `[0-9]` works.

Use:

```
[0-9]{10}
```

instead of <s>`\\d{10}`</s>